# Citizens Advice Bureau France

Tags: legal, france

In the UK we have an agency called the [Citizen's Advice Bureau](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/), they give free advice to people regarding legal matters.

I am currently travelling in france and need some legal advice.  Is there an equivalent in France (free, "starter" legal advice)?

Comment: I don't see how is this travel related

Comment: @Dirty-flow I'm traveling in france and need legal advice

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: Really?  I feel this question could be quite useful to anyone needing basic legal advice whilst travelling- especially as travelers are not likely to be well versed in french law

Answer (score 2):

France has a good online resource at https://www.service-public.fr.  By following the contact link at the bottom of the page, you can eventually reach [Vos questions (particuliers)](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vos-questions).  At the bottom of that page is a section describing how you can ask questions by telephone or e-mail.